# What is the right way to use relative paths in less stylesheets in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, less, asset-pipeline

I'm upgrading a Rails3.1 application to use the asset pipeline. I'm using `less-rails` gem to compile assets (before using asset pipeline, `more` plugin was used).

A few of existing less stylesheets reference other stylesheets in the @import directive with relative paths. There is were the problem arises, since the lookup via relative paths doesn't work.

Example:

```
first stylesheet: app/assets/stylesheets/shared/env.less
second stylesheet: app/assets/stylesheets/shared/colours.less
```

The first stylesheet is referencing the other one:

```
@import "colours.less";
```

This fails. It does start working when I modify the reference using asset helpers:

```
@import asset_path("colours.less")
```

Is this the only way to make the relative paths work? It would mean changing a lot of stylesheets references... or is the problem in my setup of `less-rails` and this should work?

**EDIT**:

Even using asset helpers doesn't work for me. The only way to get it working is by using paths starting in assets root, like this:

```
@import "shared/colours.less";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found it is OK to use relative paths hence this should work. I found it is an open issue with `less-rails` gem:

https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/pull/64

Hopefully we can solve this in short time.